# Difference between 'ns1' and 'tns' tag

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to replicate a legay NuSOAP endpoint with another implemented with PHP's native SOAP library. I'm testing by returning the same dummy array in each endpoint and comparing the xml returned by each.

The following is an example response given by the legacy server

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost/webservices-soap/servicios">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:LeerAtributosResponse xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/webservices-soap/servicios">
         <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:ParamValue[2]">.
            <item xsi:type="tns:ParamValue">
               <parametro xsi:type="xsd:string">hola</parametro>
               <valor xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[3]">
                  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">5</item>
                  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">6</item>
                  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">7</item>
               </valor>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="tns:ParamValue">
               <parametro xsi:type="xsd:string">chau</parametro>
               <valor xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
            </item>
         </return>
      </ns1:LeerAtributosResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is the response given by the new implementation:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost:8000/soap/servicios" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:LeerAtributosResponse>
         <return SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:ParamValue[2]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfParamValue">
            <item xsi:type="ns1:ParamValue">
               <parametro xsi:type="xsd:string">hola</parametro>
               <valor SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[3]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfString">
                  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">5</item>
                  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">6</item>
                  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">7</item>
               </valor>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="ns1:ParamValue">
               <parametro xsi:type="xsd:string">chau</parametro>
               <valor xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfString"/>
            </item>
         </return>
      </ns1:LeerAtributosResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I see the following differences between the responses:

- In the node 'ns1:LeerAtributosResponse' there is an extra tag
- In many fields, the new response uses the 'ns1' prefix instead of the 'tns' like the old one

What is the difference between these two tags ('ns1' and 'tns')? Will this difference in the xml make the responses different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are seeing here are "XML Namespaces". In a nutshell:

- An XML namespace is uniquely identified by a URI; the URI doesn't have to point anywhere, it's just a way of "owning" a name. For instance, SOAP envelope information uses the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`.
- Within an XML document, or even a section of an XML document, namespaces are given "local prefixes", which don't mean anything outside that document or section, and are just there to avoid writing the whole URI lots of times. These are declared with attributes like `xmlns:someprefix="http://example.com"`, and used in element and attribute names like `<someprefix:foo someprefix:bar="hello" />`
- Every section also has a "default namespace", declared like `xmlns="http://example.com"`, which defines the namespace elements are in if they have no prefix.
- A SOAP service will usually put its custom tags in a particular namespace for that service. In this case, the software is trying to make up a namespace based on where you're running the code, and coming up with either `http://localhost/webservices-soap/servicios` or `http://localhost:8000/soap/servicios`. The namespace should really be hard-coded so that it's the same wherever you deploy the service, but it doesn't really matter for testing.
- If you're writing XML by hand, you will generally assign memorable prefixes to each namespace, like `SOAP-ENV` or `soap` or `envelope` for `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`, but these don't change the meaning at all. In this case, the prefixes `tns` and `ns1` are just what the different SOAP libraries have chosen to use.

As a quick example, these pieces of XML would have exactly the same meaning:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc:example xmlns:abc="http://example.com">
     <abc:foo>42</abc:foo>
</abc:example>
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xyz:example xmlns:xyz="http://example.com">
     <xyz:foo>42</xyz:foo>
</xyz:example>
```

and even:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc:example xmlns:abc="http://example.com">
     <xyz:foo xmlns:xyz="http://example.com">42</xyz:foo>
</abc:example>
```

but this would mean something different (remember the prefix doesn't matter, only the URI):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc:example xmlns:abc="http://something.different.example.com">
     <abc:foo>42</abc:foo>
</abc:example>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a complete response. However, I have a question about the last example: In what sense does that xml means something different? Is it different because the URI is different? If I only care about reconstructing the array from the XML response, the URI shouldn't be of importance?

Comment: @MPA95 You should think of the namespace as part of the element name, so you could say that the last example contains an element called `{http://something.different.example.com}foo` but the other examples contain an element called `{http://example.com}foo`. Theoretically, a document could contain both elements next to each other, with meanings contained in completely different specifications, and namespaces were invented so you can tell them apart.